# Memory issue when loading custom fonts programmatically

Tags: ios

I want to create a framework wrapping all of my resources. In particular, I need to load some custom fonts.

There are two approach:

1. Load programmatically.

I use following code to load font data read from bundle:

```
+ (void)loadFontData:(NSData*)inData {
    CFErrorRef error;
    CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData((__bridge CFDataRef)inData);
    CGFontRef font = CGFontCreateWithDataProvider(provider);
    if (! CTFontManagerRegisterGraphicsFont(font, &error)) {
        CFStringRef errorDescription = CFErrorCopyDescription(error);
        NSLog(@"Failed to load font: %@", errorDescription);
        CFRelease(errorDescription);
    }
    CFRelease(font);
    CFRelease(provider);
}
```

And run the code in

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions;
```

However, I observe a significant increase of memory use when the app launches, and sometimes I received memory warning.

2. Add **Fonts provided by application** value in plist of the project.

This way is the usual way to add customer fonts. However, I have to expose my framework detail if using this way. For example, I have to add following value:

[image]

This method does not cause memory peak. But I want to hide my font files from people using my framework.

Could anyone help? How to load custom font programmatically without causing memory usage to explode?

Comment: First dont load all the font files, write a wrapper which load only one file as needed!

Comment: @Retro, I tried. But loading fonts will block UI. Furthermore, the first time loading a font will also increase memory usage. But using second way seems to not use memory at all.

Comment: How you are storing your font data, and from where you loading?

Comment: @Retro, they are otf files in the bundle.

Comment: so when you say you don't want to expose them, you can not put them as file in bundle, I would suggest make them blob object and store into sqlite db and load from there, else simply put into plist.

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this can avoid increasing your process memory usage.

```
bool CTFontManagerRegisterFontsForURL(CFURLRef fontURL, CTFontManagerScope scope, CFErrorRef  _Nullable *error);
```

Apple docs says:

> Fonts that are backed by files should be registered using CTFontManagerRegisterFontsForURL.